# Add policies to groups of operations in Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management

Is there's a way to apply policies to specific groups of operations in Azure APIM?

AFAIK I can only apply policies to the following scopes:

- global
- API
- operation

For my scenario I can't have some of the policies at the API (or global) scope, because some of them are not applicable to certain operations e.g. most API operations are protected by OAuth, but there's a couple of unprotected operations, so I can't put `validate-jwt` policy at the API scope. It would be nice if I didn't have to replicate the same policies for multiple individual operations.

FYI I tried adding tags to the Open API specification (which I used for the creation of the API), but I couldn't see a way to apply policies to these...

Comment: Please try this on Product-Level. Groups do not support policies

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this *yet*, but a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/12596601-policy-based-on-tags) exists which could help. You could up vote this for it gain more traction.

If applicable, one option would be to remove the `<base />` tag for the operation, preventing it from inheriting policies from higher scopes (API, Product (if present), and Global).

Comment: Upvoted that feature. Cheers.
Good to know I'm not the only one wanting this feature.